# Update path: command not found for Flutter

Tags: flutter, macos-catalina

I updated to Catalina 10.15.6 and my flutter no longer runs. I tried to update my path but have no permissions to do so. flutter worked perfectly fine before the update.

```
dxxxgxxx@dxxx-MacBook-Pro tools % flutter doctor
zsh: command not found: flutter
dxxxgxxx@dxxx-MacBook-Pro tools % echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
dxxxgxxx@dxxx-MacBook-Pro tools % $HOME/ .zshrc
zsh: permission denied: /Users/dxxxgxxx/
```

Comment: What are you trying to do be running `$HOME/ .zshrc`? The title of this questions is absolutely unsuitable for you problem. Is your problem that you think you cannot access your `.zshrc`? If yes why are you telling us about flutter? Is you problem flutter? Then why the title? To get your current `PATH` try `echo $PATH`.

Comment: My apology, I'm new. I have been running VSC for flutter and everything worked great until I updated to the newest Catalina update and my flutter is no longer found in the zsh. I tried to update the zsh but have no permission now. This is based on another thread to explain how to update the path.

Comment: Please make sure to edit the question (and the title). To update `PATH` either use e.g. `vim $HOME/.zshrc` or (to append) `export PATH=NEWITEM:$PATH`. Do you know where the flutter binary is located?